# Customized table of contents: Same indentation for every line of multi-line titles 

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

In a previous question I asked about [customizing my table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/customized-table-of-contents). For now, I have decided to fill the table of contents simply like this for each article:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\textit{\Author}\\}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{1cm} \Title \dotfill \pageref{firstpage}–\pageref{lastpage}\\}
```

But I still have no clue how to indent the line(s) containing the title (if the title extends over more than one line, all lines should be indented by the same amount):

```
=== Author's Name ===

    === Title: 1st Line ===
    === Title: 2nd Line ===
```

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Instead of adding "(2)" to denote a follow-up question, I have made the question title more specific (and changed some tags). I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example inspired of a few internal `memoir` macros, should work with any class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\newcommand\Title{This is a very long and complicated title that spans
several lines going on and on}
\newcommand\AuthorInToc[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\formatauthor{#1}}}
\newcommand\ArticleInToc[2]{\addtocontents{toc}{%
   \protect\formatarticle{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\formatauthor[1]{\noindent \textit{#1}\par}
\newcommand\formatarticle[2]{%
  \begingroup%
  \nopagebreak%
  \noindent%
  \setlength\leftskip{1cm}%
  \setlength\rightskip{4em}%
  \setlength\parfillskip{-4em}%
  \textit{Title:}~{#1}\dotfill\hbox to 4em{\hfil #2}\par%
  \endgroup%
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{test}
\AuthorInToc{An Author}
\ArticleInToc{\Title}{1--5}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to remember that each entry in the `TOC` is actually a paragraph by it self, so treat it like that.