# Chapterwise page range in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Can you give me some advice for how to obtain the following format of the TOC?

> 1. Chapter’s heading 1-7
> 2. Chapter’s heading 9-10
> 3. Chapter’s heading 11-15

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you try building some [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ? if so please post

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/customized-table-of-contents)? Probably it may solve your problem.

Comment: does the `7` mean that page `8` is blank, or that the last `\section` from the first `\chapter` is on page `7`?

Comment: It is means that last line of chapter 1 is appearing on page 7.
It may be possible that the document will be of two-sided and page 8 may be blank

Answer (score 20):

My solution consists of appropriate labeling (in the very beginning and the very end of each chapter), defining a macro `\chaprange` that retrives the pages from a pair of labels formatting them to `<p1>-<p2>` (as requested), and in redefining `\addcontentsline`. Moreover, there are three macros controlling the page numbering pattern:

1. **`\chaprangeon`** activates the functionality;
2. **`\chaprangeoff`** temporary disables the functionality;
3. **`\breakchaprange`** disables the functionality if the last chapter is *not* the content ending your document.

### The Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\if@chap@enddc
  \@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
  \expandafter\label{chap:\thechapter}}%
\let\ltx@toc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \ltx@toc
  \let\ltx@chapter\chapter
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{%
    \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
    \ltx@chapter}}%
\let\ltx@enddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand\enddocument{%
  \if@chap@enddc\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}\fi
  \ltx@enddocument}%
\newcommand\chaprange{%
  \expandafter\pageref{chap:\thechapter}--\expandafter\pageref{prenextchap:\thechapter}}%
\let\ltx@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\CR@addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\detokenize{chapter}}
  \edef\@tempb{\detokenize{#2}}
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \let\CR@thepage\chaprange
  \else
    \let\CR@thepage\thepage
  \fi
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\CR@thepage}}}%
\newcommand\chaprangeon{\let\addcontentsline\CR@addcontentsline}
\newcommand\chaprangeoff{\let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline}
\newcommand\breakchaprange{%
  \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
  \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
  \@chap@enddcfalse}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{\chaprangeon}
\g@addto@macro\backmatter{\breakchaprange}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title 1}
\lipsum

\section{Subtitle 1}
\lipsum

\chapter{Title 2}
\lipsum\lipsum

\chapter{Title 3}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\null

\appendix
\chapter{Additional Content}
\end{document}
```

> *Important*: This code requires three compilation cycles to work properly.

### Example output

[image: output]

### Updates

- **Aug/28/'15** Solution available as package [`chaprange`](https://github.com/giannotr/chaprange/tree/master/unpacked) (v0.99a: first test version)
- **Aug/08/'15** Changed the names of the user macros and fixed a few minor details in the example.
- **July/25/'15** The Code now works only on chapters without any need of patching sections, subsections, etc.
- **Oct/30/'14** Consider [this followup-question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/page-range-in-toc-chapter-entry-in-scrbook/170367#170367) if you are using sectioning commands of deeper levels than sections and have problems with the correct formatting.

Comment: In case anyone wants to combine this package with hyperref: that modification has now been made. I answered it in response to the question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597707/242407

Comment: This solution isnt working when using  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chaptername}

Comment: @Mujeebcpy -- Have you tried reading this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/page-range-in-toc-chapter-entry-in-scrbook/170367#170367?