# KOMA: Page range in TOC chapter entry

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I need to print page range in chapter entry, like

> 1. Chapter title  ------space-------      starting page number - ending page number

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic


\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}

\settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145021/27635

Comment: No "hyperref" is not used