# Page range in TOC chapter entry in scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I asked the question [KOMA: Page range in TOC chapter entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/koma-page-range-in-toc-chapter-entry)

Answer linked to [Chapterwise page range in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc)

But i do not get the result for the following code...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic


\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}

\settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@chap@enddc
  \@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\renewcommand{\@chapter}[2][]{%
\ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
\expandafter\label{chap:\thechapter}
}
\let\ltx@toc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\ltx@toc
\let\ltx@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
\ltx@chapter
}}
\let\ltx@enddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand{\enddocument}{%
\if@chap@enddc\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}\fi
\ltx@enddocument
}
\def\chaprange{\expandafter\pageref{chap:\thechapter}--\expandafter\pageref{prenextchap:\thechapter}}
\let\ltx@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\def\CR@addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\chaprange}}
}
\def\ToggleChaprange{\let\addcontentsline\CR@addcontentsline}
\def\BypassChaprange{\let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline}
\def\BreakChaprange{%
  \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
  \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
  \@chap@enddcfalse
}
\let\ltx@section\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
\BypassChaprange
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \ltx@section{#2}
\else
  \ltx@section[#1]{#2}
\fi
\ToggleChaprange
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\ToggleChaprange
\blinddocument
\BreakChaprange
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\null
\appendix
\chapter{Additional Content}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> Page range is printed for subsections also....

Comment: A simple but not pretty solution is to copy the code provided for "section" and replace each occurance of "section" by "subsection".  A better solution, would be a rewrite of the code, so only the chapter contents entries are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
  \usetocstyle{standard}
  \usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
  \settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
  \settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape\nobreakspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@chap@enddc \@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter=\@chapter
\renewcommand{\@chapter}[2][]{%
  \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
  \expandafter\label{chap:\thechapter}}
\g@addto@macro\tableofcontents{%
  \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
  \renewcommand\chapter{%
    \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
    \ltx@chapter}
  \ToggleChaprange}
\def\ToggleChaprange{\let\addcontentsline=\CR@addcontentsline}
\def\BypassChaprange{\let\addcontentsline=\ltx@addcontentsline}
\def\BreakChaprange{%
  \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
  \let\addcontentsline=\ltx@addcontentsline
  \@chap@enddcfalse}
\preto\enddocument{\if@chap@enddc\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}\fi}
\let\ltx@addcontentsline=\addcontentsline
\def\CR@addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\chaprange}}}
\def\chaprange{\expandafter\pageref{chap:\thechapter}--\expandafter\pageref{prenextchap:\thechapter}}
%Fix for sections, subsections, paragraphs and subparagraphs
\newcommand{\do@remove@chaprange}[1]{
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[2][]{%
    \BypassChaprange
    \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
      \csname ltx@#1\endcsname{##2}
    \else
      \csname ltx@#1\endcsname[##1]{##2}
    \fi
    \ToggleChaprange}}
\newcommand{\@remove@chaprange}[1]{%
  \let\do=\do@remove@chaprange
  \docsvlist{#1}}
\@remove@chaprange{section,subsection}%Applying the fix for sections and subsections
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title}
\section{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subsubtitle}
\lipsum
\chapter{Title}
\lipsum\lipsum
\chapter{Title}
\lipsum
\section{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subsubtitle}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsubtitle}
\lipsum
%\BreakChaprange
%\clearpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
%\null
%\appendix
%\chapter{Additional Content}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

> As per Andrew Swann comment i changed, it works well

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}% for sans-serif plus bold plus italic


\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}

\settocstylefeature[0]{leaders}{\hfill}%
\settocstylefeature{pagenumberhook}{\itshape~}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@chap@enddc
  \@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\renewcommand{\@chapter}[2][]{%
\ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
\expandafter\label{chap:\thechapter}
}
\let\ltx@toc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\ltx@toc
\let\ltx@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
\ltx@chapter
}}
\let\ltx@enddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand{\enddocument}{%
\if@chap@enddc\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}\fi
\ltx@enddocument
}
\def\chaprange{\expandafter\pageref{chap:\thechapter}~--~\expandafter\pageref{prenextchap:\thechapter}}
\let\ltx@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\def\CR@addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\chaprange}}
}
\def\ToggleChaprange{\let\addcontentsline\CR@addcontentsline}
\def\BypassChaprange{\let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline}
\def\BreakChaprange{%
  \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
  \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
  \@chap@enddcfalse
}
\let\ltx@section\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
\BypassChaprange
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \ltx@section{#2}
\else
  \ltx@section[#1]{#2}
\fi
\ToggleChaprange
}
\let\ltx@subsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{%
\BypassChaprange
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \ltx@subsection{#2}
\else
  \ltx@subsection[#1]{#2}
\fi
\ToggleChaprange
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\ToggleChaprange
\blinddocument
\BreakChaprange
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\null
\appendix
\chapter{Additional Content}

\end{document}
```