# How to put starting and end page number of a chapter against the chapter in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, align, page-numbering, tocloft, report

My university need toc to look like the image uploaded how to do it in latex especially how to put starting and end page number of chapter against the chapter in toc

[image]

Comment: Or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170296/page-range-in-toc-chapter-entry-in-scrbook