# Chart showing the relative number of pages in the document

Tags: page-numbering, counters, labels, charts

I'm playing with the idea of adding a chart in the begining of my thesis, showing the relative dimension of each chapter (or section, maybe). This is something that I would want to generate automatically.

**Is there a package somewhere that already allows me to do this?**

... or, failing that ...

**Is there any way I can automatically determine the number of pages of each chapter/section, so that I can feed that data to an external tool to generate the chart?**

Here's an example of how the chart could be displayed:

[image: Chart of the relative dimension of each chapter]

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but it would seem that the information used to build the table of contents (the `.aux` file) would contain the data needed to construct it.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the format of .aux files, but just gave a quick look at mine and I can't find any reference to page numbers. I'm guessing there's some additional information that is used to build the table of contents.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia: Which TeX processor are you using? LaTeX, pdfTeX, LuaTeX, etc?

Comment: @MatthewRankin I'm using pdflatex, which I think uses pdfTex under the hood.

Comment: For example, in the `.aux` file, an entry such as `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}AA}{1}}` would indicate that subsection 1.1, entitled "AA", begins on page 1.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Interesting. I missed that because I was looking only at the main .aux file (there are several .aux files, as the document is split into several .tex files). I might give it a shot if no "out-of-the-box" solution comes up.

Comment: Let me give you the advice my advisor gave me. there are two kinds of theses: a good thesis, and a done thesis.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang ... and unfortunately I don't think this particularly contributes to neither (a good or a done one), but I could think of worst ways to procrastinate :-)

Comment: Reading your question a past question did come to my mind, which could be interesting for you too, because it is in some ways the non-graphical counterpart to your approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc/145206#145206

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I got:

[image: output]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,refcount,nameref,totcount,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%% Must be placed in the preamble %%%
\newcounter{PlotMeCounter}
\newcommand{\plotted}{\stepcounter{PlotMeCounter}\label{plotme:sec\arabic{PlotMeCounter}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastplotted}{
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{
        \csgdef{totalplotted}{\arabic{PlotMeCounter}}
    }\plotted\label{plotme:secEnd}
}
\makeatother
\providerobustcmd{\totalplotted}{1}
%%% </Must be placed in the preamble> %%%

\begin{document}

%%% Can be placed anywhere %%%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\definecolor{chap1}{HTML}{6095C9}
\definecolor{chap2}{HTML}{CD665F}
\definecolor{chap3}{HTML}{AAC46C}
\definecolor{chap4}{HTML}{927AB1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1em]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstpage}{\getpagerefnumber{plotme:sec1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\numpages}{max(1,\getpagerefnumber{plotme:secEnd}-\firstpage)}
\foreach \x [evaluate={\this=\getpagerefnumber{plotme:sec\x}-\firstpage},
             evaluate={\nextx=int(\x+1)},
             evaluate={\next=\getpagerefnumber{plotme:sec\nextx}-\firstpage}]
         in {1,...,\totalplotted} {
\draw [fill=chap\x,draw=chap\x!60!black,thick]
   (\textwidth/\numpages*\this, 0) rectangle
   (\textwidth/\numpages*\next, 0.6);
}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
{\sffamily
\foreach \x in {1,...,\totalplotted} {
  \tikz{\filldraw[draw=black,fill=chap\x] (0,0) rectangle (0.5em,0.5em);}
  \nameref{plotme:sec\x}\quad
}}
\end{minipage}
%%% </Can be placed anywhere> %%%


\section{Introduction}\plotted
\lipsum

\section{Some Random Chapter}\plotted
\lipsum
\lipsum

\section{Another Chapter}\plotted
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\section{Conclusion}\plotted
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\lastplotted

\end{document}
```

How to use it:

- Place a `\plotted` after each chapter that should appear on the list.  The first occurence will be page 0 on the graph.  This way things like the titlepage or the table of contents won't be part of the graph.
- Put a `\lastplotted` after the end of the last chapter that should appear in the plot, to ignore the appendix.
- Define more colors if you have more than 4 chapters

How it works:

- `\plotted` inserts `\label{plotme:sec<counter>}`, you can later get the page number where the label was defined using `\getpagerefnumber` (note that `\pageref` does not work inside pgfmath expressions).
- `\lastplotted` saves the last value of the counter into the aux file so that in the next pdflatex pass `\totalplotted` is defined as the total number of entries.  If there's no aux file because the previous pass failed, `\totalplotted` defaults to 1, this is important as it's used as a loop variable in the tikz graphic.
- With this infos, plotting the graph is relatively straightforward, using `\foreach`, `\getpagerefnumber` and `\totalplotted`.  We also iterate over colors, so make sure that the color chap is defined for all values of the counter.
- As written in the comments, the calculations performed in `\textwidth*\this/\numpages` are fairly inaccurate as they rely on TeX-Dimensions.  So numpages*textwidth (normally between 300 and 400) must not exceed 16383.99999, thus it only works for less than 40 pages. By dividing first, `\textwidth/\numpages*\this`, we get rid of the overflow, but we loose accuracy.  Assuming a 1000 page document, we only have 4 significant digits left which may bad if you want to design the *perfect* thesis (the error has the size of approx. 0.01pt which could be measurable).  There's also the option to use the `fixedpointarithmetic` library if you want to avoid that.

Comment: That's impressive! I'm getting an error with my document though. pdflatex says `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x`. Any idea what the cause might be?

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Thanks, I missed that. The problem was that `\textwidth*\this/\numpages` can overflow [i.e. exceed 16383.99998](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54702/pgfmathsetmacro-dimension-too-large-biggest-value-allowed) for large documents. After changing it to `\textwidth/\numpages*\this` it should work fine even for larger documents.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution. The markup on @cmhughes' solution is cleaner, but the final result of this one is closer to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: After almost a year, I just found two issues with this solution: a) any idea why I can't have a ``\&`` in a chapter title with this code? :-) b) The legend wraps if the with exceeds the length of the Figure, but not always. It's not working for me for chapters with an exceptionally long title (~40 chars).

Answer (score 11):

### Update:

Most of the idea exposed in the initial version is now made automatically, adding support for unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{showkeys}

\definecolor{ylgnbu1}{RGB}{255, 255, 204}
\definecolor{ylgnbu2}{RGB}{161, 218, 180}
\definecolor{ylgnbu3}{RGB}{65, 182, 196}
\definecolor{ylgnbu4}{RGB}{37, 52, 148}
\definecolor{ylgnbu5}{RGB}{44, 127, 184}
\definecolor{ylgnbu6}{RGB}{80, 40, 84}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
   /pgfplots/bar  cycle  list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle  list={%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu1,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu2,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu3!70,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu4!20,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu5!70,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu6!70,mark=none},%
     }
   },
}

\newcounter{tmp}
% definition of 100 auxialiary counters
\makeatletter
\loop
\stepcounter{tmp}
\ifnum\value{tmp}<101
  \newcounter{nochappg\roman{tmp}}
\repeat
\newcounter{nochappg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setcounter{tmp}{0}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\setcounter{nochappg\roman{tmp}}{\value{page}}}{}{}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }%
  \global\refstepcounter{tmp}%
  \label{chap:\arabic{tmp}}%
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }%
  \global\refstepcounter{tmp}%
  \label{chap:\arabic{tmp}}%
}

\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \setcounter{nochappg\roman{tmp}}{\value{page}}%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Intro}
\lipsum[4]

\chapter*{Preface}
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum

\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-30]

\chapter{Test chapter three}
\lipsum[1-80]

\chapter{Test chapter four}
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{Test chapter five}
\lipsum[1-30]

\setcounter{nochappg\roman{tmp}}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgv

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  height=\textwidth,
  ybar stacked,
  axis lines=none,
  nodes near coords,
  bar width=20pt,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=2,
  legend style={
    at={(0.75,0.55)},
    anchor=west,
    legend columns=2
  }
]
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgi)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgii)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgiii)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgiv)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgv)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgvi)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgvii)};
\legend{\nameref{chap:1},\nameref{chap:2},\nameref{chap:3},\nameref{chap:4},\nameref{chap:5},\nameref{chap:6},\nameref{chap:7}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### To do:

1. Write the value for the counters in an auxiliary file..
2. Automate the plot at the end.

[image]

A proof of concept:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}

\definecolor{ylgnbu1}{RGB}{255, 255, 204}
\definecolor{ylgnbu2}{RGB}{161, 218, 180}
\definecolor{ylgnbu3}{RGB}{65, 182, 196}
\definecolor{ylgnbu4}{RGB}{37, 52, 148}
\definecolor{ylgnbu5}{RGB}{44, 127, 184}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
   /pgfplots/bar  cycle  list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle  list={%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu1,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu2,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu3!70,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu4!20,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=ylgnbu5!70,mark=none},%
     }
   },
}

\newcounter{nochappgi}
\newcounter{nochappgii}
\newcounter{nochappgiii}
\newcounter{nochappgiv}
\newcounter{nochappgv}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\label{chap:one}
\lipsum
\setcounter{nochappgi}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgi
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\label{chap:two}
\lipsum[1-30]
\setcounter{nochappgii}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgiii
\chapter{Test chapter three}
\label{chap:three}
\lipsum[1-80]
\setcounter{nochappgiii}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgiii
\chapter{Test chapter four}
\label{chap:four}
\lipsum[1-15]
\setcounter{nochappgiv}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgiv
\chapter{Test chapter five}
\label{chap:five}
\lipsum[1-30]
\setcounter{nochappgv}{\value{page}}
\thenochappgiv

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  height=\textwidth,
  ybar stacked,
  axis lines=none,
  nodes near coords,
  bar width=20pt,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=2,
  legend style={
    at={(0.75,0.55)},
    anchor=west,
    legend columns=2
  }
]
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgi)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgii)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgiii)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgiv)};
\addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,\thenochappgv)};
\legend{\nameref{chap:one},\nameref{chap:two},\nameref{chap:three},\nameref{chap:four},\nameref{chap:five}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The plot obtained shows a stacked bar plot corresponding to the number of pages of each chapter; the legend also contains the names for the chapters:

[image]

#### Some remarks:

1. The idea is to use a mechanism similar to the one used by the [`chappg`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chappg) package, to get the number of pages for each chapter.
2. This values are stored at the end of each chapter (this info can be written, for example, to the `.aux` file).
3. Using the stored values, [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is used to easily produce the desired plot.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution that uses the `\jobname.aux` file

[image: screenshot]

Here's how it works:

- every compilation writes a counter called `totalchapters` to the `.aux` file at the end of the document
- each `chapter` command writes counters called `totalpages<roman{chapter}>` to the `aux` file; I've used `roman{chapter}` because `LaTeX` doesn't like having numbers in command or counter names
- each compilation will, of course, read information back from the `\jobname.aux` file, so you'll need two compilations to get the right numbers.

The first time you run it, you should see the following in your `jobname.log` file:

```
Defining a new counter: totalpagesi
Defining a new counter: totalpagesii
Defining a new counter: totalpagesiii
Defining a new counter: totalchapters (3)
```

On the second run, you should see:

```
Total pages for Chapter 1 match auxilary file (3)
Total pages for Chapter 2 match auxilary file (6)
Total pages for Chapter 3 match auxilary file (13)
Total Chapters match auxilary file (3)
```

I haven't put the labels automatically on the chapters yet- you could lift that part from Gonzalo's answer, otherwise I'll pick it up again soon. Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\totalchapters}[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{c@totalchapters}
    {%
        \newcounter{totalchapters}
        \setcounter{totalchapters}{#1}
        \typeout{Defining a new counter: totalchapters (#1)}
    }%
    {%
        \ifnum\value{totalchapters}=#1
        \typeout{Total Chapters match auxilary file (#1)}
        \else
        \typeout{Warning: total Chapter count updated from \the\value{totalchapters} to #1-- recompile to fix}
        \fi
        \setcounter{totalchapters}{#1}
    }%
}
\newcommand{\definetotalpagecount}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{c@totalpages\@roman{#1}}%
    {%
        \newcounter{totalpages\@roman{#1}}
        \setcounter{totalpages\@roman{#1}}{#2}
        \typeout{Defining a new counter: totalpages\@roman{#1}}
    }%
    {%
        \ifnum\value{totalpages\@roman{#1}}=#2
        \typeout{Total pages for Chapter #1 match auxilary file (#2)}
        \else
        \typeout{Warning: total pages for Chapter #1 updated from \the\value{totalpages\@roman{#1}} to #2-- recompile to fix}
        \fi
        \setcounter{totalpages\@roman{#1}}{#2}
    }%
}


\preto\chapter{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\definetotalpagecount\string{\thechapter\string}\string{\the\value{page}\string}
    }
    \fi
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\definetotalpagecount\string{\thechapter\string}\string{\the\value{page}\string}
        \string\totalchapters\string{\thechapter\string}%
    }
}

\newcommand{\drawPageChart}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xbar stacked,
                xmin=-0.1,
                %ymin=0,ymax=1,
                bar width=40pt,
                nodes near coords,
                axis lines=none,
                nodes near coords align={horizontal},
                visualization depends on=x \as \myxcoord,
                nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\myxcoord},
                every node near coord/.append style={
                    anchor=east},
            ]
            \@ifundefined{c@totalchapters}
            {}
            {%
                \foreach \i in {1,...,\thetotalchapters}{%
                    \addplot coordinates {(\the\value{totalpages\@roman{\i}},0)};
                }
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \drawPageChart
    \caption{Blueprint of my thesis}
\end{figure}


\chapter{}
\lipsum
\chapter{}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm accepting @texnokrat's answer because his final result is much closer to what I was looking for, but this one wins the "cleanest markup" award :-) Well done.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia no worries :) I might come back to this and polish it a little in the future- glad you got a result you can use :)