# How to use visualcounters in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, counters

I want to use `Progressbar` in my LaTeX document.
I found some idea from [the visualcounter module by Aditya Mahajan](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/t-visualcounter/doc/context/third/visualcounter/visualcounter.pdf),
  but I don't know how to utilize that one.
Because I am new to LaTeX, any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you're referring to some functionality provided by [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), then head over to [Progress bar for `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59742/5764).

Comment: I'm afraid that nobody will be able to give you much help without more information. You seem somewhat confused. LaTeX is a set of macros built upon TeX. ConTeXt is an *alternative* set of macros. You cannot use context modules with latex. Moreover, what does `latex3` have to do with it? Please post a Minimal Working Example showing what you are trying to do so that people have at least *some* idea what you are asking. That is, post a short, compilable document starting with `\documentclass` (if you want to use latex) and complete with `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: sort of relevant: [Chart showing the relative number of pages in the document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155789)

Comment: Also related: [Visual counter for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140619/13304)