# Page number start and end in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to insert both start-page-number and end-page-number in ToC? It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: like this? [Chapterwise page range in the TOC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145021)

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you. I could not find this question, and I posted it. Now I am closing this question.