# Chapterwise page range in the TOC including bibliography and index

Tags: table-of-contents

> Follow-up question to [Chapterwise page range in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc)

The provided solution is working fine with chapter's range only. But, it is not working with the References' section and the Appendix. Can you kindly provide a suitable solution?

Comment: Perhaps you should first accept the very sophisticated answer by Ruben first, before asking basically the same question again `;-)`

Comment: My solution in that post is able to include the page range also for those parts of the document. But, as I wanted to showcase you can break the functionality earlier. Just delete or comment out `\BreakChaprange` and it will work for the whole document.