# List of Listings (LOL) multiple entries with the same name

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I splitted some source code into various listing all with the same name "Company ontology" (to use the `firstnumber=auto`), now in my LOL I have multiple repeated entries, is there a way to solve, maybe with only one entry Company ontology 13-14?

[image: See attached image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It is important to know how you implemented the List of Listings.

Comment: I don't think such a compression of LoL entries is possible with `listings`; I'd say that implementing that feature in `\lstlistoflistings` would be far from trivial...

Comment: Is it really necessary, to make an entry to the LOL for each of this 'sublistings'?

Comment: It is not the same problem, but points to the same direction and perhaps the solution by user Ruben there can be adapted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc