# When I used the code below or the package chaprange, then it gave me a problem with the hyperlink package and table of contents

Tags: tables, packages, hyperlink

```
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\if@chap@enddc
  \@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
  \expandafter\label{chap:\thechapter}}%
\let\ltx@toc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \ltx@toc
  \let\ltx@chapter\chapter
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{%
    \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
    \ltx@chapter}}%
\let\ltx@enddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand\enddocument{%
  \if@chap@enddc\expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}\fi
  \ltx@enddocument}%
\newcommand\chaprange{%
  \expandafter\pageref{chap:\thechapter}--\expandafter\pageref{prenextchap:\thechapter}}%
\let\ltx@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\CR@addcontentsline}[3]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\detokenize{chapter}}
  \edef\@tempb{\detokenize{#2}}
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \let\CR@thepage\chaprange
  \else
    \let\CR@thepage\thepage
  \fi
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\CR@thepage}}}%
\newcommand\chaprangeon{\let\addcontentsline\CR@addcontentsline}
\newcommand\chaprangeoff{\let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline}
\newcommand\breakchaprange{%
  \expandafter\label{prenextchap:\thechapter}
  \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
  \@chap@enddcfalse}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{\chaprangeon}
\g@addto@macro\backmatter{\breakchaprange}
\makeatother
```

Comment: With hyperlink package you mean hyperref?

Comment: And I guess this where you got the code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145206/242407

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. Yes, I mean hyperref. Yes, I took the one you mentioned. The problem is that the guy who wrote the code used the Idea of label and ref for chaprange, so this Idea is not bad but it is breaking hyperref.

Comment: I've been trying a bit, and know where the problem is, but I've not found a clean way to solve it yet. I'll look at it tomorrow evening; unfortunately, I don't have any spare time left right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old code called `\addtocontents` directly, which bypasses logic of `hyperref`. That breaks LaTeX, so instead this solution calls the complete `\addcontentsline`, but with `\thepage` replaced by `\chaprange`, using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`.

[image: Chapter range + hyperref]

Since it's a lot of code, I recommend to put it in a separate file, as a package. For this, in the same directory as your document, create a new file called `hchaprange.sty` and add the following code to it:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{hchaprange}[2021/05/21 hchaprange v1.0]

% Change page number of chapters in table of contents to a page range
% Source (original idea):
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc/145206#145206
% Source (hyperref modification): 
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597707/when-i-used-the-code-below-or-the-package-chaprange-then-it-gave-me-a-problem-w?noredirect=1#comment1498939_597707

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\newif\csname ifishyperrefloaded\endcsname

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
    \ishyperrefloadedtrue
}{
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \unless\ifx\texorpdfstring\undefinedcmd
            \ishyperrefloadedtrue
        \fi
    }
}

% Classic label expands too, but I prefer to do the expansion explicitly
\def\xlabel#1{%
    \edef\labelcontent{#1}%
    \expandafter\label\expandafter{\labelcontent}%
}

\expandafter\newif\csname if@chap@enddc\endcsname
\@chap@enddctrue
\let\ltx@@chapter\@chapter

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
    \ltx@@chapter[#1]{#2}
    \xlabel{chap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}
}

\let\ltx@toc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
    \ltx@toc
    \let\ltx@chapter\chapter
    \renewcommand{\chapter}{
        \xlabel{prenextchap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}
        \ltx@chapter
    }
}

\let\ltx@enddocument\enddocument
\renewcommand\enddocument{
    \if@chap@enddc
        \xlabel{prenextchap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}
    \fi
    \ltx@enddocument
}
\newcommand\chaprange{%
    \ifishyperrefloaded
        \pageref*{chap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}--%
        \pageref*{prenextchap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}%
    \else
        \pageref{chap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}--%
        \pageref{prenextchap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}%
    \fi
}%

\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\ltx@addcontentsline\addcontentsline

    \newcommand{\CR@addcontentsline}[3]{
        \edef\@tempa{chapter}
        \edef\@tempb{#2}
        \let\tempcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
        %
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
            \patchcmd{\tempcontentsline}{\thepage}{\chaprange}{}{
                \PackageWarning{ChangeChapterHyperref}{Couldn't patch command to chaprange!}
            }
        \fi
        \tempcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}
    }
}

\newcommand\chaprangeon{
    \let\addcontentsline\CR@addcontentsline
}
\newcommand\chaprangeoff{
    \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
}

\newcommand\breakchaprange{
    \xlabel{prenextchap:\csname thechapter\endcsname}
    \let\addcontentsline\ltx@addcontentsline
    \@chap@enddcfalse
}

\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{\chaprangeon}
\g@addto@macro\backmatter{\breakchaprange}
```

Now in your document you can use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hchaprange}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title 1}\label{sec:sometest}
\lipsum

\section{Subtitle 1}
\lipsum

\chapter{Title 2}
\lipsum\lipsum

\chapter{Title 3}
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\backmatter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\null

\appendix
\chapter{Additional Content}
\end{document}
```

That should do the trick! Hope you're happy with it! Took me quite some time, because there was messing with the `\thepage` for a while (it turned out to receive a very special treatment). But then I learned about this handy `\patchcmd` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I appreciated that.